# Spring Security authorization for certain URL and deny all others

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have below configuration class where I would like to authorize certain requests and deny all others.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/phx-config-rest/dev/master").hasRole("DEV")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
            inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("devuser")
                .password("dev")
                .roles("DEV"); 
    }
}
```

As per this code my impression was, Spring will only allow me to access /phx-config-rest/dev/master using the user 'devuser' and If I try access /phx-config-rest/prod/master or any other url, request would considered as un-authorized access. BTW, this code piece is regarding Spring cloud config server. Any thought?

Answer (score 4):

change the

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

to

```
 .anyRequest().denyAll()
```

Answer (score 4):

You restrict only URL `/phx-config-rest/dev/master` to users with role `DEV`, but all other URLs are accessible for every logged in user (including user `devuser`) with any role, 
see [`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl#authenticated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#authenticated--):

> Specify that URLs are allowed by any authenticated user.

You have to use [`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl#denyAll`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#denyAll--) instead of `authenticated`:

> Specify that URLs are not allowed by anyone.